# Not able to find the Activity name for Uber app for appium

Tags: appium

I tried to find the activity name for uber app using aapt tool.
Not getting the activity name.Can anyone help for this.

Below are the commands i have used:

1. C:\rohit\android_sdk\build-tools\23.0.1>adb shell pm list packages -f | findstr
   uber 
   Output:/data/app/com.ubercab-2/base.apk=com.ubercab
2. C:\rohit\android_sdk\build-tools\23.0.1>adb pull /data/app/com.ubercab-1/base.apk
3. C:\rohit\android_sdk\build-tools\23.0.1>aapt dump badging base.apk|findstr launchable-activity

Getting no output after 3rd command.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to run the listed commands for the signed/non-debug build of the Uber app which you probably would have installed via Play Store.

The 'launchable-activity' attribute of a package cab be extracted only for the debug apps.

Before releasing the app build to Play Store, it is signed with a private key, which prevents the app logs to be read in the Android Studio or Monitor console and cyphers other information of the app.

If you are looking for some random application for your practice, you can search for an debug app on Google. I believe you can find several debug apps as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

For Android, the best way to find the appActivity is by using this command - `dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus'`

This gives the package & activity name of the app which is currently in focus. Steps -

1. Connect phone to computer with USB
2. Open cmd and run `adb shell`
3. Open uber app on the phone, so that it is the app in focus
4. Run command `dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus'`

This will show appPackage and appActivityName

You can check this link for more details - [Find appPackage and appActivity name for Android app](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/apppackage-and-appactivity-name/)